# Indexing using UPPER function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

I am trying to create the indexes using the liquibase using following query in SQL Server.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX LASTNAME_IDX ON EMPLOYEE(UPPER(LAST_NAME));
```

But I am getting the error while running the liquibase. It works fine in oracle. Let me know if there a way I can create the index in SQL Server

Comment: please elaborate on your issue

Comment: With default collation SQL Server is case insensitive (Oracle is case sensitive), so creating index on UPPER is not needed, just index the column.

Comment: The next time you encounter an error you don't understand - post the complete error message. No one should need to guess about such things. As Piotr mentiones, there is no reason to do this if you are using a case-insensitive collation for that column.

Answer (score 8):

SQL Server does not support function indices, which Oracle does support.  One workaround here would be to create a computed uppercase column, and then index that:

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD LAST_NAME_UPPER AS UPPER(LAST_NAME);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX last_name_idx ON EMPLOYEE(LAST_NAME_UPPER);
```